# Default argument followed by variable length arguments (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function that takes one positional argument, one default argument, variable length non keyword arguments and variable length keyword arguments. The function looks like below:

```
def set_football_team(name,
                     coach = '',
                     *players, **formations):
    print("Team: "+name)
    print("Coach: "+coach)
    for i, player in enumerate(players):
        print("Player "+str(i+1)+": "+player)
    for position, positional_players in formations.items():
        positional_players = ", ".join(positional_players)
        print(position+": "+positional_players)
```

It is working fine when all arguments are passed.

```
name = "Real Madrid"
coach = "Zinedine Zidane"
players = ["Keylor Navas", "K. Casilla",
           "Sergio Ramos", "Varane", "Marcelo"]

formations = {"Goalkeeper": players[:2],
              "Defender": players[2:]}

set_football_team(name, coach, *players, **formations)

Output
==============================================
Team: Real Madrid
Coach: Zinedine  Zidane
Player 1: Keylor Navas
Player 2: K. Casilla
Player 3: Sergio Ramos
Player 4: Varane
Player 5: Marcelo
Goalkeeper: Keylor Navas, K. Casilla
Defender: Sergio Ramos, Varane, Marcelo
```

But when I skip passing `coach` it shows unexpected output even I set `coach` to an empty string in the argument:

```
name = "Real Madrid"
players = ["Keylor Navas", "K. Casilla",
           "Sergio Ramos", "Varane", "Marcelo"]

formations = {"Goalkeeper": players[:2],
              "Defender": players[2:]}

set_football_team(name, *players, **formations)

Output
==============================================    
Team: Real Madrid
Coach: Keylor Navas
Player 1: K. Casilla
Player 2: Sergio Ramos
Player 3: Varane
Player 4: Marcelo
Goalkeeper: Keylor Navas, K. Casilla
Defender: Sergio Ramos, Varane, Marcelo
```

I know the order of function arguments:

`positional argument > default argument > variable length non keyword arguments > variable length keyword arguments`

What is the reason of the above behavior? What am I missing?

**How can I overcome this?**

Comment: `*players` gets unpacked to separate args, and the first one is going to be assigned to `coach`. You can get around that by calling it like `set_football_team(name, players=players, **formations)`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how the coach got the first value. Even in that case the player names are shown like `players: Keylor Navas, K. Casilla, Sergio Ramos, Varane, Marcelo` which is not desired.

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't notice that. That happens because doing `players=players` makes the `players` list another keyword arg, so it gets printed by the same code that prints the keyword args created by the `**` unpacking of `formations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set_football_team(name, coach, *players, **formations)
```

When the function is called as above with coach is passed as argument, coach is assigned the value which is passed in argument for function set_football_team.

```
set_football_team(name,*players, **formations)
```

When the function is called as above when no coach argument is passed explicitly, coach is primarily being assigned first value of *players, the remaining values of players are passed on to players,which is why you notice only 4 players in players while the 0th element in the list got assigned to coach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How can I overcome this?

Comment: you can pass empty string as argument to avoid this. 
   `set_football_team(name,' ', *players, **formations)`